# Java casting resulting in run-time error instead of compilation error

Tags: java

The following code snippet will result in a run-time:

```
class Vehicle {
    public void printSound() {
        System.out.print("vehicle");
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    public void printSound() {
        System.out.print("car");
    }
}

class Bike extends Vehicle {
    public void printSound() {
        System.out.print("bike");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle v = new Car();
        Bike b = (Bike) v;

        v.printSound();
        b.printSound();
    }   
}
```

My question is: why does that result in a run-time error but not a compilation error? Shouldn't the compiler know that 'v' is already a 'Car' and cannot be cast into a 'Bike'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In theory, it would be possible for a compiler to say to itself: "`v` is local variable, that is assigned to be a `Car`. At no point prior to the attempted cast to `Bike` does it change its value, and there is no way for `Car` to be successfully cast to `Bike`. Therefore, this is an error."

However, I know of no Java compiler that will do that analysis for you. It's really only worthwhile in the simplest of cases. Instead, the behavior is that the compiler sees the cast, and reasons that it is possible to cast a `Vehicle` to a `Bike`, and so it allows it.

In general, that's what a cast means: it tells the compiler that even though this assignment might fail, you're pretty certain that it won't. In exchange for allowing the code to compile, you assume the risk of a run-time exception.

Answer (score 5):

Casting from super class may work, so it is allowed (during compilation). Casting from a totally different class is not allowed, for example:

```
Integer a = 1;
String b = (String)a; // compile error
String b = (String)(Object)a; // runtime error
```

Answer (score 4):

For

```java
R r = /* some code to initialize "r" */
T t = (T) r;
```

The *Java Language Specification* says:

> If R is an ordinary class (not an array class):
>
> - If T is a class type, then R must be either the same class   as T or a subclass of T, or a run-time exception is thrown.
> - If T is an interface type, then R must implement  interface    T, or a run-time exception is thrown.
> - If T is an array type, then a run-time exception is thrown.

Comment: Nice and simple explanation. For future reference straight to JLS SE8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 1):

Type casting of object occurs at run time so compiler doen't recognize it

Answer (score 0):

No. `v` is a `Vehicle` and it might be possible to cast it to `Bike`. It's not the compiler's job to figure out the actual runtime types of every object (especially because sometimes that's impossible).

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of Java say that this must result in a run-time error. In this case it's possible to look at the code and see that it will definitely throw an error at runtime, but how does the compiler know that a `ClassCastException` isn't what you wanted?

Editors like IntelliJ and Eclipse can (and do) notice these kinds of errors and warn you about them, but the rules of Java say that this is legit code that must compile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a runtime error because you already defined the variable `v` as a `Car`. You cannot convert `Car` to `Bike`.

The compiler will not check this kind of value assignment because compilers in general do not check semantics.