# Cast a superclass to a subclass

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, casting

Imagine a class **Cottage extending Building** and the code

```
Building building = new Building();
Cottage cottage = (Cottage)building;
```

Now, it totally makes sense that **Building** cannot be casted to **Cottage** considering the nature of java's inheritance, but what doesn't make sense (to me) is that this compiles. Why does it compile and then throw a runtime **ClassCastException**?

Isn't it obvious that **building** is a reference to a **Building** object before actually running the program?

Being such a general question, I know I am getting a possible duplicate for this one :) but I couldn't find an answer to WHY DOES IT COMPILE question :)

**EDIT2** I accepted a great answer here (let alone the discussion below it :) ), but I still find the accepted answer in [Java casting resulting in run-time error instead of compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388136/java-casting-resulting-in-run-time-error-instead-of-compilation-error) the most interesting...

**EDIT** I edited **IllegalCastException** and put the correct **ClassCastException**

Comment: a lot of "obviously wrong" things compile in java. like e.g. `int x = 5 / 0`

Comment: The cast operator explicitly tells the compiler to **not** be type-safe.

Comment: The title is a bit different, but it's exactly a duplicate of my question. thanks... Moreover, the explanation given by @dlev there is great...

Comment: There's no such thing as an `IllegalCastException` - that should be `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because, compiler does not know what object does your reference `Building` is referring to.

So, in the below case, where you have a *base class* reference, pointing to *sub class* object: -

```
Building building = new Cottage();
Cottage cottage = (Cottage)building;
```

It would work perfectly fine. So, it's completely a *runtime* decision, as to whether it is a valid cast or not. Hence, compiler won't throw error for that.

> Isn't it obvious that building is a reference to a Building object
>   before actually running the program?

**No.** Absolutely not. The type of object being referenced, is not known till runtime. Always remember that, *Compiler* always checks the *reference type*. Actual object type is checked at runtime.

This concept is known as *Polymorphism*, where you can have the same reference type to point to objects of various subtypes. You can google it, and would get lots of resources to read.

Comment: Hmmm... call me stupid, but we both now, reading these 2 lines of code what each reference holds and so does the compiler... Exception makes sense when you work with, for example, a Collection holding Objects and you expect a certain type so U cast, but in such a simple case it could tell. no? In the "possible duplicate" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388136/java-casting-resulting-in-run-time-error-instead-of-compilation-error @devl explains it really nicely.

Comment: ...a bit offended by "This concept is known as Polymorphism" comment :(

Comment: @luigi7up.. Couldn't really understand your first comment. And why offended in your 2nd comment?

Comment: @luigi7up.. See this tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: @luigi7up.. `and so does the compiler` - No the compiler doesn't know the actual type being referred by the reference. As I said, compiler only checks that the reference type is valid. For e.g., if you perform a cast like this: - `Number num = (Number)(date);`, here the compiler will obviously complain, because it knows a `Date` reference cannot be casted to a `Number` reference, no matter what implementation of `Date` you use? So, it is sure that this will fail at runtime, and hence gives you an error.

Comment: __As I said, compiler only checks that the reference type is valid__
I am only trying to say that in cases as simple as this one it could check it for us just by "reflecting" the code... Thank you very much for such a quick replies...

Answer (score 3):

Part of the function of casting is it makes the compiler shut up, you are saying that you know better than the compiler what the object you're casting is. If the cast is not accurate you get an exception.

Maybe you expect the compiler is tracking what object things are pointing to and working out if the reference is plausible. The compiler is not that smart and is easily fooled, see this snippet:

```
    int i = 1;
    System.out.println((Number)i);        
    Object o = i;
    System.out.println((String)i); // won't compile (primitive-to-ref-type cast)
    System.out.println((String)o); // compiles (thanks to autoboxing)
```

The compiler cares only about preventing conversions between primitives and reference types.

Comment: this makes sense and helps a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating an Cottage(Subclass) object with Building(super class) reference

```
Building b= new Cottage();
Cottage c = (Cottage) b;
```

The above code is legal, thus the compiler wouldn't know what object does the reference variable `c` refer to at run time, thus compiler wouldn't throw an error.

> Why does it compile and then throw a runtime IllegalCastException?

BTW, it throws **ClassCastException** when you try to cast an superclass object into subclass, not **IllegalCastException**.