# why it is possible to new an array of an interface

Tags: java, arrays, interface, casting

Why the following is possible in Java ?

```
Integer[] ints = (Integer[])new Comparable[10];
```

But it gets `ClassCastException` at runtime. What is the usecase to `new` an array of an interface.

Comment: java indentifies types at runtime. Casting cannot hide real type.

Comment: An `Integer` is-a `Comparable`, but a `Comparable` isn't necessarily an `Integer`.

Comment: This is not creating the instance of Interface, it is creating a class that implements interface.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the specific question:

```
Comparable toComplare[] = new Comparable[10];
```

Why not create an array that will allow you to store *any* object that implements the Comparable interface?!

The point is: the **interface** denotes a "common functionality" - and it *could* be helpful to *only* look at objects from that "view".

Of course, the *objects* stored in that array are always of some "real" class - but all these objects will implement the functionality that the `Comparable` interface provides.

So you could do things like:

```
toCompare[0] = new Integer(5);
toCompare[1] = new BigDecimal("3.2");
...
```

I am not saying that this is something that you would use frequently, but as said - it allows you to "collect" objects under a certain, specific "view" of their capabilities. It is also worth pointing out: having such an array does **not** mean that you would be able to do:

```
toCompare[0].compareTo(toCompare[1]);
```

successfully!

Beyond that: a *cast* always implies somehow that you, the programmer know something the compiler doesn't know. So the compiler steps back and lets you do that - assuming you know what you are doing. But as the code you are showing in the question is obviously *not* correct, reality comes back biting you at runtime. And yes, it would be possible to decide at compile that the given code is incorrect.

Comment: In this particular case, a static analyzer would probably also flag it at compile-time.

Comment: @Thilo Correct; I added another sentence about that. The fact that the compiler doesn't complain here is probably the most interesting aspect of this question.

Comment: The compiler cannot reject it as per language spec. (But it might issue a warning, we've seen more and more of these being added over the years)

Comment: @Thilo Can you point to the specific section in the JLS you have in mind here?

Comment: Still looking for it. For now, related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388136/java-casting-resulting-in-run-time-error-instead-of-compilation-error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467999/cast-a-superclass-to-a-subclass?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: FWIW, they could add new static type check errors every time they define a new language version. So a `-target 9` could include it. Similar to how we now have "effectively final" variables we did not have before (those lead to code being compiled that did not compile before, though, rather the opposite of what we have here)

Comment: Also somewhat related: Unreachable code *error* vs Dead code *warning*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141029/unreachable-code-error-vs-dead-code-warning-in-java-under-eclipse

Comment: Probably Section 5.5.1: "If S is an array type SC[], that is, an array of components of type SC: [....] If T is an array type TC[], that is, an array of components of type TC, then a compile-time error occurs unless one of the following is true:  [...] TC and SC are reference types and type SC can undergo casting conversion to TC."  Which means, as long as `Comparable` can be cast to `Integer`, the same can be done of arrays of those.

Answer (score 1):

Regard this case: You have an interface and two (or more) classes that implement that interface:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    public void someMethod();
}

class MyClass1 implements MyInterface
{
    public void someMethod() { System.out.println("foo");}
}

class MyClass2 implements MyInterface
{
    public void someMethod() { System.out.println("bar");}
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyInterface[] array = new MyInterface[2];
    array[0] = new MyClass1();
    array[1] = new MyClass2();

    array[0].someMethod();
    array[1].someMethod();
}
```

An array of an interface gives you the method of holding different implementations of that interface in an array

Comment: Explain the downvote please? Have i mistaken something?

Answer (score 1):

Having `Integer` implement `Comparable`, doesn't mean `Integer[]` implements `Comparable[]`, so you can't convert arrays of different type. You can, however, put `Integer` in element of `Comparable[]` array.

Comment: This is wrong. You can absolutely assign an `Integer[]` to `Comparable[]`.  This compiles and runs just fine: `Comparable[] x = new Integer[10];`

Comment: This is completely opposite what I wrote. Try this `Integer[] ints = (Integer[]) new Comparable[] { 1 };`, and you will receive `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Comparable; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;`

Comment: You wrote "`Integer[]` does not implement `Comparable[]`". That is false. Every `Integer[]` is also a `Comparable[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler looks at the type of the right side, and sees that it is an array of `Comparable`. In general, it *could* be an `Integer[]` (because that is assignable to `Comparable[]`).

*We* know that it will not be an `Integer[]`, because that right-hand expression is a constructor call. But the compiler does not look that far. It uses the same logic as if that expression was a method call with a declared type of `Comparable[]`. It does not look inside to figure out the actual type.

So the compiler will accept your typecast, because it *might* succeed. It will only reject casts that cannot work out at all (according to declared types), such as casting `Integer` to `String`.

Note that it is probably a design flaw to allow this co-variance in arrays. You can cast `Integer[]` to `Comparable[]`, but this has problems and for this reasons you *cannot* cast `List<Integer>` to `List<Comparable>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reason for `ClassCastException` is due to **Heap Pollution**. 
   Find more details here http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ050
2. Use case of `new` to an interface array / just interface is to fill it with any class object which *implements* that interface (or) give an *anonymous inner class definition*.

Comment: Heap pollution cannot happen with arrays, as they check the component type at runtime (it is not erased as it is with generic collections). You get ArrayStoreExceptions if you try to put in something bad.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are performing a *Narrowing Reference Conversion*

The class Integer implements the Comparable interface:

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>
```

see: [5.1.6. Narrowing Reference Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6)

> From any array type SC[] to any array type TC[], provided that SC and TC are reference types and there is a narrowing reference conversion from SC to TC.
>
> Such conversions require a test at run time to find out whether the actual reference value is a legitimate value of the new type. If not, then a ClassCastException is thrown.