# SCJP subSet() has to be casted to (TreeSet<Integer>)

Tags: java, collections, scjp, treeset

I found a curious SCJP question that at first looks as if it was answered correctly:

```
TreeSet<Integer> s = new TreeSet<Integer>();
TreeSet<Integer> subs = new TreeSet<Integer>();
for(int i = 606; i < 613; i++)
    if(i%2 == 0) s.add(i);
subs = (TreeSet)s.subSet(606,true, 630,true); 
s.add(629); 
s.add(630); 
System.out.println(s + " " + subs);
```

I shared the opinion with the others that this would print [606, 608, 610, 612, 629, 630] [606, 630]. I tried compiling it and to my surprise found out that the code gives a compile error with a warning:

```
__[unchecked] unckecked conversion__
found: java.util.TreeSet
required: java.util.TreeSet(java.lang.Integer)
```

It does compile if I cast the s.subset like this:

```
subs = (TreeSet<Integer>)s.subSet(606,true, 630,true);
```

I found various examples similar to this on the net and no one says that this code doesn't compile. I am confused regarding the correct answer here

I'm compiling it with the compiler 1.6 > so it shouldn't be compiler version issue

**EDIT:** The short answer is YES, IT COMPILES and long one is: read the accepted answer :)

Comment: Why are you surprised that the raw cast gives a compiler warning?

Comment: I had no idea that compiler checks possible casting issues for you... To my knowledge, compiler was playing dumb when you cast: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388136/java-casting-resulting-in-run-time-error-instead-of-compilation-error as you can see in this discussion compiler can see that you're trying something stupid, but doesn't warn you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the compile time error. It is indeed the warning message that came because you compiled your code in this way 
`javac -Xlint:unchecked MyTreeSet.java`
 where , `MyTreeSet.java` is the name of your java file.

> **You still will have the class file generated successfully in your
>   working directoy**

Comment: Oh, thanks... I saw it was a compile warning and guessed that the compilation was failing... I compiled without -Xlint, though...